How are helicopters's avionics powered during power-off autorotation?
Avionics such as an altimeter or a radio require electric power to work. The engine usually provides this power. How is this electric power supplied in case of engine failure?
I can think of the following solutions:

Batteries
APU
Using the shaft to turn an electric turbine (this could generate some unwanted torque)
Expecting the pilot to do without

What is the most common solution? Does it depend on the size or application of the helicopter?

Autorotation will only last a few seconds, so batteries will certainly power for the radios. The altimeter and many other instruments will be passive, if they are steam gauge dials.

FYI: Altimeters that work entirely from static air pressure are still very common today.  Many GA aircraft only have these, many aircraft with glass cockpits have them as an emergency backup.

Some helicopters will likely have standby instruments with their own backup power

On smaller rotorcraft the electrical generator can be a starter-generator, also used as a starter. On larger rotorcraft an independent alternator is usually installed on each engine. On largest rotorcraft, like CH-47, an APU is present, but is used only on the ground.
Generators/alternators are driven by an engine shaft, not by a rotor shaft, to supply electricity when the engine works, even when the rotor is still stationary, isolated by the clutch(es).
In case of all-engines failure, the only source of electricity for autorotation is the battery.
On a single-engine Bell 407:

With generator OFF, a fully charged battery will provide approximately 21 minutes of power for basic helicopter and one VHF COMM radio (35 minutes with optional 28 ampere/hour battery).

Source: Bell 407 Flight Manual.
The battery capacity allows a normal autorotation landing, which cannot last more than a few minutes. The longest descent would be from the service ceiling. Rough calculation:

Starting at the ceiling of 20 000ft,
with a maximum glide distance of 14 NM,
with a minimum speed of 55 KIAS,

the glide cannot last more than about 15 minutes (the longest helicopter autorotation is likely 30 minutes, from an altitude of 40 200 ft).

On small rotorcraft the electrical generator is reversible and is also used as a starter...  Not necessarily.  Rotorway, for example, (a kit-built 2-seater) uses a modified automotive engine with a normal automotive starter and alternator (and a bunch of other parts too).  You can even get them from car parts stores and use them as-is, if you know what cars originally used them.  (you can do that with experimental)

did they really write ampere/hour instead of amperehour battery in that source?!?... Addidionally: 15min in autorotation glide, wow! That would have to feel like an eternety to the pilot!

@kruemi: They did, common mistake but unexpected in a manual. The record for autorotation is about 30 minutes, when Jean Boulet reached the altitude of 40 800 ft in a Lama and the engine flamed out (many components had been removed to save weight, including the starter and the battery immediately after the engine had been started)
